# How to delete phrase not specified in a gsub

Tags: r, regex

I have a column in a dataframe that is full of text (of varying lengths) such as

```
'Nature of specimen= D2x4, stomach biopsies\nbalblablablabl\nabla\nSomeRandomText\nNature of specimen= Colonx2, polypx1\nMore Random Text\nNature of specimen= TIx2, polypx1\n'
```

I want to only extract `Nature of specimen.*?\n` so that I am left with :

```
Nature of specimen= D2x4, stomach biopsies\nNature of specimen= Colonx2, polypx1\nNature of specimen= TIx2, polypx1\n
```

I think I need to gsub everything that is not `Nature of specimen.*?\n` but I don't know how to negate a whole regex. At the moment I tried

```
`df$Text<-gsub("[^(Nature of specimen.*?\n)]","",df$Text`
```

but that just remove each character in the regex from the text rather than the intended output.

Comment: I think the most natural way would be to grab the desired pieces instead of eliminating the unwanted ones.. e.g. `regmatches(txt, gregexpr("Nature of specimen=.*?\n", txt))[[1]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not a `regex` solution(terrible at that) but using here `strsplit`:

Basically I'm splitting it up on "\n" and then selecting every alternate values and pasting it back

```
paste0(unlist(strsplit(x, "\n"))[c(TRUE,FALSE)], collapse = "\n")
[1] "Nature of specimen= D2x4, stomach biopsies\nNature of specimen= Colonx2, polypx1\nNature of specimen= TIx2, polypx1"


library(stringr)
paste0(unlist(str_extract_all(x, pattern = "Nature of specimen=.*\n")), collapse = "")
```

Comment: OK. Nice idea but in some of the text a \n is part of the stuff I want to exclude. I will add that in to the example text as I hadnt seen that as a pattern. Point given but cant accept

Comment: @SebastianZeki i agree, another solution fom `stringr` too!

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I forgot about str_extract_all

Answer (score 1):

We can also use the more efficient `stri_extract` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
paste(stri_extract_all_regex(str1, "Nature of specimen=.*\n")[[1]], collapse="")
#[1] "Nature of specimen= D2x4, stomach biopsies\nNature of specimen= Colonx2, polypx1\nNature of specimen= TIx2, polypx1\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
library(stringr)
str_match_all(text, ".*(Nature\\s+of\\s+specimen[^\\n]+)\\n")[[1]][,2]
# [1] "Nature of specimen= D2x4, stomach biopsies" "Nature of specimen= Colonx2, polypx1"       "Nature of specimen= TIx2, polypx1"
```